# Verify test(s) exist for any source/destination mapped types

Tags: java, unit-testing, modelmapper

My understanding of "best practices" when using an automatic mapping tool like [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) is to have unit tests for any source->destination map that occurs in your code, to be sure the mapping is doing what you expect.

Is there any code coverage/static analysis tools that would assist in determining that for every invocation of `ModelMapper#map` source/destination pair, there exists a unit test that invokes `ModelMapper#map` with the same source/destination types?

Comment: There is probably nothing readymade. However, you could parse the Byte code of any class of your project and check for such invocations from your unit tests. I would however not recommend this, rather make it explicit by a dedicated parametic test.

Comment: @raphw I am writing such tests now, but I am hoping for a way to verify that I didn't skip writing a test in haste by verifying a test exists for any map call in the code.

Comment: Then you would need the above manual verification. But why do you need this feature for so many classes in the first place? Finding such errors is normally a job for a type system. You should avoid dynamic type mapping whereever applicable.

Comment: I have several situations requiring mapping: mapping domain classes yo DTOs for serialization in HTTP responses, and mapping equivalent classes from a set of web services with effectively identical classes, but different packages.

Comment: I have had the same issue plenty of times and I feel your pain. However, I found it better to refactor my classes in order to make such mapping obsolete whenever possible. Otherwise, I would recommend you to maybe add annotations to your classes (some `@MapsTo` for example and scan the entire application for such classes. Then, I would write a single test that verifies that any such mapping is tested which you could check by a naming convention for your test cases.